# Android app crashing after push notification is received while running in background

Tags: android, crash, push-notification, titanium, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm developing an app with titanium but when I test it on android it crashes occasionally when receiving push notifications in background. On the iOS version this is not causing any problem.

I'm using an Android with 4.4.2 version installed and Titanium SDK 3.4.0
Here's the crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.hitabis.elsa.mobile/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tabgroup.TiUIActionBarTab$TabFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tabgroup.TiUIActionBarTab$TabFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1801)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:213)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:97)
at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onCreate(TiBaseActivity.java:473)
at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity.onCreate(TiActivity.java:18)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.tabgroup.TiUIActionBarTab$TabFragment; no empty constructor
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:402)
... 20 more
```

Comment: error on this line TiBaseActivity.java:473

Comment: What does that actually mean? I still can't find my error